# Validator extend method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, extend

I'm trying out a creative approach towards the Validator::extend method.
There is 1 function from a custom class `SchemaValidator` that we need in the `Validator` class.

in SchemaValidator.php

```
public function getValidated()
{
    return array_intersect_key ($this->getData(), $this->getRules());
}
```

in app/start.php

```
Validator::extend('getValidated', 'SchemaValidator@getValidated');
```

And finally, where we call the regular Validator class

```
$validator = Validator::make ($input, $rules);

// ... some error checks

return $validator->getValidated();
```

However, this fails. Did I forget anything?
Or am I right in my fears that I'm just abusing `Validator::extend` ?

edit:
The error output

```
BadMethodCallException
Method [getValidated] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full path to your SchemaValidator class. IE:

```
Validator::extend('getValidated', '\App\Services\SchemaValidator@getValidated');
```